# how to reopen my OpenShift app

Tags: web-applications, openshift

On Dec 28, 2015 at 01:38:58 PM the OpenShift operations team flagged your application for excessive network resource use.

We noticed that your gear is transferring an excessive amount of data.

We want to thank you for your adoption of our platform. Unfortunately, our free tier is not intended for the kind of heavy usage that your application demonstrates. Our Acceptable Use Policy at https://www.openshift.com/legal/acceptable_use states the following:

> While we strive to make our service as useful as possible, we don't
>   support all workload profiles on the OpenShift Online free service.
>   Distributed processing or other activities that continuously exhaust
>   a specific resource (e.g. CPU, Network, Memory) are not allowed.
>   Applications are allowed to consume available resources for a short
>   period of time, but not continuously.

Because of this, your application has been throttled. The system will automatically turn throttling on and off as your usage levels change. You will not be notified about future throttling actions related to this gear. We encourage you to consider upgrading to one of our paid tiers where you will receive an increased allocation of system resources. Please see www.openshift.com/pricing for more information about our paid tiers and the benefits they provide.

You can contact us at developers.openshift.com/en/contact.html

The Red Hat OpenShift Team

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be directed to the OpenShift team.  It is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1) A workaround: Get you data out of your OpenShift instance, create new one and migrate everything to the new instance (but OpenShift OPs can do the same with the new instance as well).

2) Do what OpenShift wants: upgrade to paid plan

3) Move out of OpenShift elsewhere (for example [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) seems very nice).

Yesterday I also got email from OpenShift and at the end decided that 3rd option is for me best. More information: http://www.topjavablogs.com/news/free-openshift-tier-it-was-a-nice-dream-but-that-s-all.html